# How to change/add lights from all directions to the obj in Blender?

Tags: python, blender

I have a question about the blender rendering, so my mesh in meshlab looks like 1st image but after I ran this [script](https://github.com/yinyunie/depth_renderer/blob/main/render_all.py#L236) I got RGB like 2nd/3rd images (left, right and top are black, apparently affected by the light), I'm wondering how to set up the lighting so the lighting shoot from all the directions to the obj so the rendered images do not affect by the lights? or any other solutions?

[image]
[image]
[image]

I think this is the only lighting set up in the script.

```
def light_setting_init():
    """ light settings for renderer
    """
    # Make light just directional, disable shadows.
    world = bpy.data.worlds['World']
    world.use_nodes = True

    # changing these values does affect the render.
    bg = world.node_tree.nodes['Background']
    bg.inputs[1].default_value = 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the material type of your model to **Emission** with a strength value of 1.0